# How to reconcile this apparent flaw in Chamber of Secrets about knowledge of Voldemort's identity?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

There are a number of threads discussing who knew Voldemort = Riddle. However, none seem to go one step further and use this to challenge the credibility of the plot of the Chamber of Secrets.

Here is an exposition of the flaw.

1. Let us first consider the canonical case where only a few people (Dumbledore, Bellatrix and other Death Eaters/friends of Riddle from Hogwarts and possibly Ollivander) knew.

   As a subcase, first let us suppose that no investigation of Voldemort’s identity took place. That is, no journalist at the Daily Prophet or detective at the Ministry (henceforth investigator) bothered to conduct an investigation into the background of the most infamous wizard in the world. Let’s rule this out on the grounds that it is too implausible.

   Indeed, following Voldemort’s “death” during his first encounter with Harry, a number of the Death Eaters were sent to Azkaban. So some form of investigation surely took place. These investigators would have sought to identify the members of Voldemort’s gang. They would have noted that Bellatrix and other Death Eaters were close friends of Tom Riddle (Hogwarts’ most accomplished student). They would note that Tom Riddle is nowhere to be found (after Voldemort enters the public domain). They would also note that Voldemort is widely known to have attended Hogwarts and Slytherin in particular. They would then note that there are no other obvious candidates for Voldemort’s true identity. So even though they did not hold hard evidence for the hypothesis Voldemort = Riddle, they would surely have strong suspicions. Suspicions that would be strengthened by the events surrounding Hagrid’s expulsion. Based on these suspicions, they would surely have investigated further and interrogated Bellatrix and others (perhaps Dumbledore) to see whether they could help prove or disprove the hypothesis Voldemort = Riddle.

   The question then becomes: **why didn’t one of those few** (Dumbledore, Bellatrix, etc) **simply reveal their knowledge regarding Voldemort’s identity to investigators?** What’s their incentive to lie? For Death Eaters, the only incentive might the fact that Riddle’s diary is a Horcrux: indeed one that relies on duping the reader into thinking Voldemort is not Riddle. But this does not explain Dumbledore or Ollivander’s reasons for revealing/not revealing their knowledge. Surely Dumbledore would wish to reveal this information, precisely because this would weaken Voldemort’s position. *Moreover, the canonical view is that Ollivander knew, and he did not even try to hide his knowledge from the 11-year-old Harry (when Harry purchased his wand in the Philosopher’s Stone). From this we might reasonably conclude that Ollivander’s close friends would have known. That the close friends of close friends of Ollivander knew, and so on. Since this gossip would be hot property, it would travel like wild fire.*

   Then, as in the investigations surrounding real-life bad characters (such as Hitler or Stalin), the main hypotheses (that Voldemort = Riddle) would be publicised and would eventually attain the status of common knowledge. So we arrive at a contradiction of our initial assumption that very few knew.
2. Now let us consider the alternative case where, contrary to Dumbledore’s statement, many people knew that Voldemort = Riddle.

   In this case, Mr Weasley, as a member of the Ministry of Magic, would know. Then, the Weasleys would all know, and so therefore would Ginny. Then she would not have fallen for Riddle. Indeed Harry, Ron and certainly Hermione, would have known, undermining the main mystery of the plot of the Chamber of Secrets.

Is there any credible way to reconcile this apparent flaw in the plot?

Comment: Okay for 2. That a 11 year old girl. And you want her mom to tell her remember the real name of a killer which is assumed death ??? Like dumbledore do you know his full name, this should apply with voldemort

Comment: For 1. Reveal the name of a terrorist for what? Ppl fear Voldemort and that name alone is enough( like what Hagrid said in vol 1). And like in ww2 do every ppl in europe try to find what happens with Hitler's childhood. No that happens decade after ww2 when ppl forget it.

Comment: They probably couldn't get anyone to publish the investigations. People were afraid of taking about Voldemort, so the newspapers and book publishers were worried it would hurt their PR or wouldn't sell. Voldemort is Voldemort, but the bottom line is the bottom line.

Comment: @someoneuseless Exactly _because_ people fear the name “Voldemort” alone it would be very useful to publish details about his earlier years since it would humanise him. People fear the unknown. Voldemort seems a lot less scary if you know how he started out as a kid in an orphanage. Of course he’s still scary in that scenario but certainly a lot less so than when imagined as some kind of faceless immortal half-god?

Comment: What exactly is it about the propoganda-ridden, status-quo-preserving, change-resistant Daily Prophet that makes you believe they were interested in impartial investigative journalism? Why do you believe that the government which falsely imprisoned Hagrid, Sirius Black and many others is capable of competent, thorough and evidence-based enquiries? ;)

Comment: @11684 Sort of.  The fact that people are still afraid of his name shows that they still consider him present in some way, a threat to them.  And publicly diminishing a still-existing threat makes you the prime target for it.  This would give pause to any publisher when dealing with someone like Voldemort and the Death Eaters.  We have real-world examples of publishers refusing to publish articles / quotes / cartoons due to concerns of being targeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Credit where credit is due**. I agree with Alex that the minimum requirement for the plot is that Harry, Hermione, Ron and Ginny do not know.

**The rest of this answer is novel**:

It is probably fair to say that not many people know Joseph Stalin's original surname is Jughashvili: he chose to adopt his pen name after he wrote an essay that was well-received. He adopted this pen name because it sounds like Lenin, means “man of steel” and because he thought it would give him a better chance of success.

I make the comparison with Stalin with some reservations because there is only one school of magic in the country, so the British wizard community is relatively small. Tom Riddle, as a precocious head boy, would already have been quite famous by the time he left Hogwarts.

I think that the Stalin comparison may provide just enough cover for the minimum requirement (that Harry and friends + Ginny do not know) for the plot to succeed. There is a chance that Harry and Hermione's muggle upbringing and Ron and Ginny's remote upbringing would mean they didn't know. This would be more convincing if the Chamber of Secrets was the first book in the series. But it's not.

Ultimately, I think the answer lies at the "meta level". The Chamber of Secrets is intended to deepen our understanding of the wizarding world from Harry's perspective, not be a flawless depiction of truth. I think JK Rowling had thought of the issues raised here and she decided the second story was to contain a revelation of Voldemort's past. She chose the most interesting way to simultaneously reveal to us and Harry the identity of Voldemort. *We have to discover "the truth" with Harry.*

**Example (an alternative plot that doesn’t work)**: JK Rowling could have let Voldemort/Riddle choose a new pseudonym and false character for the diary (with which to dupe Ginny and Harry). Whilst this might provide a more water-tight plot, I expect JK Rowling would reject it on the grounds that she would not have been able to involve Hagrid and others who confer the truth. The diary is playing the vital role of revealing the truth to us.

Comment: What a Strange StackExchange this is. This was a popular question that was mothballed by the petty little powers that be. Here is the private feedback I was given.

Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.

Closed 16 hours ago by Stormblessed, Dave Johnson, Sava, TheLethalCarrot, Shreedhar.

(Private feedback for you)

Answer (score 43):

## Dumbledore wanted the Dark Lord to think his secrets were safe.

Dumbledore wouldn’t have told the rest of the wizarding world that the Dark Lord was once called “Tom Riddle” because he didn’t want the extent that he knew of the Dark Lord’s past known. That was likely to keep him confident in how well his secrets were hidden, so he wouldn’t suspect Dumbledore knew of the Horcruxes and decide to increase their protection. When Dumbledore started telling Harry about the Dark Lord’s past, he also told Harry to make sure no one else would know other than Ron and Hermione, so he certainly didn’t want it widely known.

> “Sir, am I allowed to tell Ron and Hermione everything you’ve told me?’
>
> Dumbledore considered him for a moment, then said, ‘Yes, I think Mr Weasley and Miss Granger have proved themselves trustworthy. But, Harry, I am going to ask you to ask them not to repeat any of this to anybody else. It would not be a good idea if word got around how much I know, or suspect, about Lord Voldemort’s secrets.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 10 (The House of Gaunt)*</sup></sub>

Dumbledore made the conscious choice to not share his knowledge of the Dark Lord’s past, not wanting the Dark Lord to become more cautious with his secrets, particularly his Horcruxes.

## Death Eaters would respect the Dark Lord’s wishes.

The Death Eaters who knew the Dark Lord’s former identity would not choose to share this with the rest of the wizarding world, out of respect, fear of what he might do, or a mixture of both - including the ones who knew him then that later became Death Eaters.

> “As he moved up the school, he gathered about him a group of dedicated friends; I call them that, for want of a better term, although as I have already indicated, Riddle undoubtedly felt no affection for any of them. This group had a kind of dark glamour within the castle. They were a motley collection; a mixture of the weak seeking protection, the ambitious seeking some shared glory, and the thuggish, gravitating towards a leader who could show them more refined forms of cruelty. In other words, they were the forerunners of the Death Eaters, and indeed some of them became the first Death Eaters after leaving Hogwarts.
>
> ‘Rigidly controlled by Riddle, they were never detected in open wrong-doing, although their seven years at Hogwarts were marked by a number of nasty incidents to which they were never satisfactorily linked, the most serious of which was, of course, the opening of the Chamber of Secrets, which resulted in the death of a girl. As you know, Hagrid was wrongly accused of that crime.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 17 (A Sluggish Memory)*</sup></sub>

Those who knew him then would also know that he despised the name and its implications, so knowing that, would not choose to share the knowledge widely.

> “TOM MARVOLO RIDDLE
>
> Then he waved the wand once, and the letters of his name re-arranged themselves:
>
> I AM LORD VOLDEMORT
>
> ‘You see?’ he whispered. ‘It was a name I was already using at Hogwarts, to my most intimate friends only, of course. You think I was going to use my filthy Muggle father’s name for ever? I, in whose veins runs the blood of Salazar Slytherin himself, through my mother’s side? I, keep the name of a foul, common Muggle, who abandoned me even before I was born, just because he found out his wife was a witch? No, Harry. I fashioned myself a new name, a name I knew wizards everywhere would one day fear to speak, when I had become the greatest sorcerer in the world!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 17 (The Heir of Slytherin)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, Death Eaters would not be proclaiming to the wizarding world the Dark Lord’s former identity.

## Very few others knew who could tell.

Knowledge of the Dark Lord’s former identity was limited to very few people, so there were not many people who could conceivably share it with the wider wizarding world.

> “Very few people know that Lord Voldemort was once called Tom Riddle. I taught him myself, fifty years ago, at Hogwarts. He disappeared after leaving the school … travelled far and wide … sank so deeply into the Dark Arts, consorted with the very worst of our kind, underwent so many dangerous, magical transformations, that when he resurfaced as Lord Voldemort, he was barely recognisable. Hardly anyone connected Lord Voldemort with the clever, handsome boy who was once Head Boy here.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 18 (Dobby’s Reward)*</sup></sub>

Dumbledore and the Death Eaters had their own reasons for not telling the wider wizarding world, and there were not many others who knew. The Ministry didn’t seem to be aware, so they couldn’t spread it, and any average wizarding citizens who suspected or knew the Dark Lord’s former identity wouldn’t necessarily think the information would be particularly helpful - there’s an extremely powerful Dark Lord bent on conquest, it wouldn’t matter to the average wizard who he was in school.

## Journalists are unlikely to investigate.

It seems highly unlikely that any journalist would want to look into the Dark Lord’s past to see who he used to be. Before his final downfall, the Dark Lord was either a very real and present threat or someone that enough wizards feared the memory enough to the point of fearing speaking his name. Even after he disappeared, most people thought he was still out there somewhere, so no one would want to needlessly provoke him.

> “Some say he died. Codswallop, in my opinion. Dunno if he had enough human left in him to die. Some say he’s still out there, bidin’ his time, like, but I don’ believe it. People who was on his side came back ter ours. Some of ’em came outta kinda trances. Don’ reckon they could’ve done if he was comin’ back.
>
> ‘Most of us reckon he’s still out there somewhere but lost his powers. Too weak to carry on.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 4 (The Keeper of the Keys)*</sup></sub>

This meant investigating his past would feel quite dangerous for seemingly little reward - the highest priority with a Dark Lord would be stopping him, and knowledge of his childhood wouldn’t seem particularly useful or relevant to that aim. Additionally, even should anyone investigate, the Prophet wouldn’t likely have been willing to print a story like that. After the Death Eaters break out of Azkaban, Rita Skeeter tells Hermione that the Prophet won’t print a story claiming the Dark Lord had returned.

> “You *want* me to report what he says about He Who Must Not Be Named?’ Rita asked Hermione in a hushed voice.
>
> ‘Yes, I do,’ said Hermione. ‘The true story. All the facts. Exactly as Harry reports them. He’ll give you all the details, he’ll tell you the names of the undiscovered Death Eaters he saw there, he’ll tell you what Voldemort looks like now – oh, get a grip on yourself,’ she added contemptuously, throwing a napkin across the table, for, at the sound of Voldemort’s name, Rita had jumped so badly she had slopped half her glass of Firewhisky down herself.
>
> Rita blotted the front of her grubby raincoat, still staring at Hermione. Then she said baldly, ‘The Prophet wouldn’t print it. In case you haven’t noticed, nobody believes his cock-and-bull story. Everyone thinks he’s delusional. Now, if you let me write the story from that angle –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 25 (The Beetle at Bay)*</sup></sub>

As Rita Skeeter explains to Hermione, the Ministry would not want the Prophet printing it, and the wizarding public would not want to read it. An expose on the Dark Lord’s true identity would likely face these same obstacles, with the added one of it not being urgent news important to know.

> “There’s no market for a story like that,’ said Rita coldly.
>
> ‘You mean the Prophet won’t print it because Fudge won’t let them,’ said Hermione irritably.
>
> Rita gave Hermione a long, hard look. Then, leaning forwards across the table towards her, she said in a businesslike tone, ‘All right, Fudge is leaning on the Prophet, but it comes to the same thing. They won’t print a story that shows Harry in a good light. Nobody wants to read it. It’s against the public mood. This last Azkaban breakout has got people quite worried enough. People just don’t want to believe You-Know-Who’s back.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 25 (The Beetle at Bay)*</sup></sub>

Because of this, investigating the Dark Lord’s past is likely to be a frightening prospect with not many feasible benefits or effects on the wizarding world, so it’s unlikely anyone would want to.

Comment: Wow, that first section is surprising. I read the header and thought "*why?* you're going to need to come up with some pretty compelling evidence for that - surely making Voldemort = Riddle public knowledge, hence making him seem more human and less bogeymanish, would be in line with Dumbledore's *'fear of a name increases fear of the thing itself'* policy?" But in that quote you did indeed provide sufficiently compelling evidence :-) I guess I'd half forgotten that Dumbledore always knew Voldemort was still out there and quite likely to come back.

Comment: I'm still not convinced by your *last* section though. "*knowledge of his childhood wouldn’t seem particularly useful or relevant*" - why not? Any psychologist would tell you how important someone's childhood can be to understanding them, and understanding Voldemort better would humanise him, make him seem more defeatable and less an all-powerful supervillain. And those quotes from Skeeter are from a different era, when it's "against the public mood" to even discuss Voldemort. Immediately after his first downfall, I reckon the public could've done with some reassurance that he was only human.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, the wizarding world does not appear to be well supplied when it comes to Muggle luxuries like psychologists.

Comment: @HarryJohnston But the point is valid, regardless of whether or not there's an actual psychologist to say it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, I don't think it's a point that would occur to a wizard, though.  It only seems obvious to us because we've seen it as a cliche on too many TV shows.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've never seen it in a TV show (don't watch much TV).

Comment: @Randal'Thor, read in a newspaper then.  Point is you live in a culture where the importance of psychological profiling is taken for granted.  I'm not sure that's the most important question though - would the Ministry really have wanted to downplay Voldemort's villain cred after his apparent defeat?  It would risk making them look incompetent for having failed to stop him themselves.  And the public mood at that time was positive, one might even say euphoric, so from the Ministry's point of view at least I don't think reassurance was needed.

Comment: I don't think the first part is necessarily correct. When Dumbledore says that he doesn't want Voldemort to find out how much Dumbledore knows about his past, he was talking about information that required deliberate research and investigation into Voldemort's past. He didn't want Voldemort knowing that he was engaging in such activities. But Voldemort already knew that Dumbledore knew that Voldemort was Tom Riddle – they had a whole conversation about it in one of the memories Harry visited in *Half-Blood Prince*.

Comment: Dumbledore knowing this information wouldn't indicate anything, and thus there would be no reason to hide it. Additionally, Dumbledore did in fact tell people that Tom Riddle and Voldemort were the same person. At the end of *Chamber of Secrets* he announces it to a room full of Mr. and Mrs. Weasley, Harry, Ron, Ginny, and McGonagall, and does not even caution them not to repeat that information.

Comment: @Randal'Thor "surely making Voldemort = Riddle public knowledge, hence making him seem more human and less bogeymanish" I'm not sure that's an improvement, really. Knowing the monster was just an ordinary disaffected human creates the fear that another like him could easily arise again, and encourages extreme measures to be taken to prevent that. Granted, I don't know if Dumbledore would think that way, but I do.

Comment: Can't find it now, but wasn't there already a question here about why dumbldore wanted to call voldy by the name voldemort and not tom riddle?

Comment: 'Secrets and lies, that's what we grew up on' - Aberforth

Answer (score 14):

There are number of things at play here. **First, people want to put Voldemort behind them.**

This is the reason for Fudge's complete denial. Someone like Rita Skeeter wants to do something that sells, and something that won't be suppressed. And oh boy does the wizarding community like to suppress things. It's only once the Quibbler starts down a different path that the door is even open to that. And it wasn't suppressed immediately because for so long it wasn't taken seriously enough for them to bother. Remember too that Rita only did it because she was blackmailed into it. Before that, she did was WANTED by the powers that be.

**Second, who he WAS is both valuable and dangerous information. If it's common knowledge that Tom Riddle is Lord Voldie, then people would investigate. And they might find what Harry found. Horcruxes, or other dangerous objects.** For this reason, someone like Dumbledore, who wouldn't want other people digging into it would want to suppress or keep this out of the public eye. For people like Fudge revealing that he was once just an ordinary wizard isn't good. So many different sides have reasons not to have that be public knowledge.

**Third, the fear of Voldemort and his followers is still there and very real.** There are still powerful wizards who support him. With political power. Another side that wouldn't want him to seem small or pitiful. And who would enjoy being "in the know" as it were. And look at how much Lord Voldie HATES his former identity. He wouldn't want it spoken of at all, so his followers would respect that and most likely continue it.

**Fourth, Tom Riddle doesn't matter to most people. They don't care who he was. Lord Voldemort matters. The identity he took on overshadows his former identity.** Look at how they DON'T speak his name.

**Fifth, consider what the Daily Prophet actually is and what it isn't. What it isn't is free press.** Look at what they publish in other books and why. Besides the Lovegood publication, it seems to be the only source of news. And the Daily Prophet is most definitely, scarily influenced and perhaps even run by the powers that be, that is, the politicians of the wizarding world.

The answers to these questions aren't actually in the *Chamber of Secrets*. They are in the fabric of the world built, and are slowly revealed over time. Quite honestly, I find the wizarding community's insular quality and suppression of free press terrifying.

Rita Skeeter only published her book on Dumbledore once Dumbledore was dead, AND the illusion of free press was shattered. Before that Quibbler interview, everyone believed in the Daily Prophet as a true source of news. There was nothing else.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this challenges the credibility of the plot, and I think that the other answers here may be overthinking this as well. Put simply, the fact that Tom Riddle is the same person as Lord Voldemort is not very well known but it is hardly a closely guarded secret. For instance, at the end of *Chamber of Secrets* Dumbledore had no problem announcing it to a group consisting of three young schoolchildren, a teacher, a low level Ministry employee, and a housewife. Nor did he caution any of them not to share the information with others.

All that is necessary for the plot to be reasonable is that Harry, Ron, Hermione, and Ginny were unaware of this bit of information. They were the only ones that were aware of the diary and would have acted differently had they associated Tom Riddle with Voldemort.

It is hardly surprising that they were not aware of this. Harry had never even heard of Voldemort until a year prior. He got the bare-bones story from Hagrid, and probably picked up additional details from some of his friends, but the association with Tom Riddle was not something that he would have likely found out about without deliberately trying to. Hermione as well had only been introduced to the wizarding world when she started at Hogwarts, and though she read a bunch of books it is not far-fetched that the ones that she read did not mention Voldemort's original name. We also don't see Hermione doing much research to try to find out who Riddle was (perhaps somewhat out of character?) other than checking his award in the trophy room.

Ron and Ginny, though born to a wizarding family, were mere babies when Voldemort was defeated. Anything they knew about Voldemort would be what they heard about it years later. The Weasleys seem like the type to to not tell their young children more than they have to about Voldemort. What his name was as a young student would almost certainly be considered a superfluous and irrelevant detail, and in any case Mr. and Mrs. Weasley may not have been aware of it themselves (as implied in the passage when Dumbledore tells them). Young Ron and Ginny were hardly the type to go seeking out those kind of details even if they were readily available, so it's not really surprising that they didn't know it.

In short, I don't think we need to rely on any conspiracies here. The facts were known by some, but apparently not announced to the whole wizarding world. Those who knew, knew. Those who didn't know, didn't know. It apparently never became necessary for the general public to specifically be made aware of this, but it wasn't necessarily deliberately censored either.

Comment: I like this answer better than the others because the minimum requirement is indeed an absence of knowledge on the part of Harry, Ron, Hermione and Ginny. But, I find it difficult to believe that, after their first encounter with Voldemort (in the Philosopher's stone), they didn't seek more information about Voldemort's background. It is common knowledge that he went to Slytherin, so why not his original name? I think the story of who and how he became The Dark Lord would be a fascinating part of common folk lore. I would accept your answer if Chamber of Secrets was the first book.

Comment: Also, if it is fairly well known as you suggest earlier in your answer, let's consider Ron and Ginny's knowledge. Five older siblings, all active and curious wizards, plus a dad in the ministry, and this never came up over dinner, or by the fireside, or during play? The older brothers (Bill and Charlie) would have been in their late teens early twenties when Voldemort "died". Would this not have been a topic for discussion given that they went to the same school? Wouldn't this be useful information for banter with Slytherin peers? I mean this is the only school for magic in Britain.

Comment: @user1211719 I don’t think it’s “fairly well known”. I just think it’s not a closely guarded secret. Bill and Charlie were in their late teens early twenties at the time of *Chamber of Secrets*. Voldemort’s defeat was eleven years prior to that so they would have not even been teenagers yet.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected. But now put yourself in the shoes of someone who arrives at Hogwarts even a year or two after his death. You’re told that Voldemort was at Hogwarts and everyone’s been talking about his death (since Harry is famous). Wouldn’t you be curious to know more? What was he like when he was here? What stories are there from when he was here?